# Tinymce editor image upload plugin upload path url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, plugins

I am using an image uploader plugin called justboil.com (jbiimages) for tinymce editor.

When I upload image it is working fine on localhost, but on website image is not uploading. It's showing:

> Upload in progress… This is taking longer than usual. An error may
>   have occurred

The domain and path is 
http://www.testsite.com/admin/upload_images/img1.jpg

Here is the config code for the plugin

```
$config['img_path'] = '/admin/upload_images'; // Relative to domain name

$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path'];
```

I've added `relative_urls: false, remove_script_host: false,` in init but my image is not uploading and I'm getting two errors in console those are:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   GET:http://www.testsite.com/admin/js/tiny_mce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/blank/english
>   404 (Not Found) 
>   POST:http://www.testsite.com/admin/js/tiny_mce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english
>   404 (Not Found)

Comment: path is correct. in my localhost iam getting correctly. but in server iam getting "/var/chroot/home/content/s/d/e/sdeeco123/html/admin/uploaded_images"

Comment: did you check folder permissions? you probably need a write permission to that folder..